# What does the Blade and Soul item level mean?

Tags: blade-and-soul

Yesterday I noticed that I had a repair hammer that was level 1-10.  I was level 19 so figured it was useless but tried to repair using it just to be sure and it worked.
I have assumed that the item level meant usage, but it does not appear so at least for that item.  Does anyone know (can source) what it means?

My current guess is now "what levels you can find it" however that's kind of weird, since I could always return to the low level areas and find those items if that's the case.  Maybe something lost in translation?

On the opposite side of the coin, I have a few items from the daily dash that are higher level and those have a lock symbol which I assumed meant I couldn't use them because of my level, now I wonder about that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level of repair tools means what level of weapons can be repaired with it.
The level of weapons and equipment is at which character level you can wear/use them.

Levels - a common limitation to low-level players to not use the high-level gear in most MMORPG/RPG

Comment: Thank you.  Did you have a source or is this personal experience/knowledge?

Comment: @joedragons, it's personal experience from Taiwan, Japan, Russian and Euro servers of Blade'n'Soul, also tens of other MMORPGs